# How to download file PDF using FileResult but "only" via $ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, fileresult

This is the web method definition:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult GenerateReport(string Id) {
     //............Code .................//
 return File(response.ReportContents, "application/pdf");

}
```

and here is my jQuery ajax call to web method:

```
$(".ValuationReport").bind('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost.com/Report/GenerateReport
            type: "POST",
            data: { Id: "00AFCA2F-6809-4FF4-BA32-125EAEBB1321" },
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Please help me.

Comment: have you tried something please show the code.

Comment: Help you with what? You haven't really asked a question (the title is not sufficient). Please explain more clearly what you want to do, and why the code you've quoted doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't download files using an ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

you havent mentioned the problem you are really facing with your current approach, as it happens you cannot download the file using the XMLHTTPRequest, with your current approach a download dialog should appear as a response to your ajax request because the browser will unable to understand the `"application/pdf"` ContentType and will try to download the file